# How do I enable visual editor on Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia

When I click on Beta features on the English Wikipedia I see only `Completion suggester`, `Other projects sidebar`, `Hovercards`, `Read more`, `Compact language links` and `Content Translation`. I don't see a box for enabling the visual editor. How do I enable the visual editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VisualEditor is no longer under Beta features. To enable it, go to the ["Editing" section of your preferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Preferences#mw-prefsection-editing) and uncheck the box that says "Temporarily disable the visual editor while it is in beta," the last option under "Editor."